# Complicated XML structure being hard to query with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

A colleague at work is having an issue with a very unusual XML file when trying to query it and after trying to help him, me and the other guys are in a bit of a creative block....look at this, it might interest many people here....

Structure:

```
<Root>
 <MainFoo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla="bla" />
        <B bla1="blablabla" />
        <C bla2="blabla" />
        <Bar N="Education" V="Some Text" />
        <Bar N="Other Node" V="Some other Text" />
        <Bar N="Yet Other Node" V="Some other other Text" />
        <Bar N="fourth Bar Node" V="Some other other otherText" />
        <Bar N="UserID" V="1" />
     </Foo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla="bla" />
        <B bla1="blablabla" />
        <C bla2="blabla" />
        <Bar N="Education" V="Specific Text" />
        <Bar N="Other Node" V="Some other Text" />
        <Bar N="Yet Other Node" V="Some other other Text" />
        <Bar N="fourth Bar Node" V="Some other other otherText" />
        <Bar N="UserID" V="2" />
     </Foo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla="bla" />
        <B bla1="blablabla" />
        <C bla2="blabla" /> <!--***No Bar node with N="Education" in this Foo Node, not a mistake! this might be part of the problem but this is the XML Structure and can't be changed***-->
        <Bar N="Other Node" V="Some other Text" />
        <Bar N="Yet Other Node" V="Some other other Text" />
        <Bar N="fourth Bar Node" V="Some other other otherText" />
        <Bar N="UserID" V="3" />
     </Foo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla="bla" />
        <B bla1="blablabla" />
        <C bla2="blabla" />
        <Bar N="Education" V="Specific Text" />
        <Bar N="Other Node" V="Some other Text" />
        <Bar N="Yet Other Node" V="Some other other Text" />
        <Bar N="fourth Bar Node" V="Some other other otherText" />
        <Bar N="UserID" V="4" />
     </Foo>
 </MainFoo>
 <OtherMainFoo></OtherMainFoo>
 <MoreMainFoo></MoreMainFoo>
</Root>
```

OK, Now for the issue at hand:
we are trying with LINQ to XML to get every **User ID value For Every user Node** into a string for every **Foo Element** ***IF*** There is a **Bar node** in this **Foo and the N attribute** of this **Bar node is "Education"** and only if this **bar node with attribute education has the V with a value that not contains words that we specify in the LINQ**

For example, if we want all the user IDs for Foo nodes with education don't contain the word ***"Some"*** we will get the result of 2,4 because Foo number one had a Bar node with education value for the N attribute but it has the Some string in the V Attribute and Foo number 3 Don't have a Bar Node with an Education value in it's N attribute (Very important, because we think this is one of the reasons that we are getting empty result all the time what ever we do).

Any LINQ to XML expert here that have an idea, this is a very unusual scenario for an XML but that is was we have to deal with and i thing that this question will interest many people over here.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Is there a reason to use linq for this task?  The business rules here sound better suited to system.xml

Comment: First, Won't happen again John, and To Hogan, why not use LINQ? it should do every thing that System.xml does to query XML Structure but faster and with less lines of code and faster, Or am i wrong? isn't that the all idea around LINQ to XML? why is it better to use XML Node query here then LINQ?

Comment: @Erez - exactly as I said - one is better than the other depending on the use case.  If you have no idea how to do it in linq, but a good idea how to do it in System.xml, that is a good indication of a) System.xml is better or b) You don't know Linq.  My guess is it is a), but I'm working on a linq answer for you, give me a few minutes

Comment: There is a typo in the opening and closing tags `<MAinFoo>` and `</MainFoo>`

Comment: Yes, The typo is here, not in the original XML, Fixed it....Thank you.

Comment: What did we try? Every thing we can, and we are did some pretty complicated queries in the past, never came in such a conundrum? In general, as I see it the issue is that we need to query multiple nodes with the same name and find that: 1. exists, 2. has the N that is "Education", then for this node Check that the V attribute don't contain certian words and for every node that correspond to this rules  go to the sibling node that is called User and get the value of the ID attribute. We and I did many tries, there is no point writing all of them here, unless people want to know what didm't work

Comment: Please look and the Edit, the Node is not UserID, it is another Bar Node with an attribute of N equals UserId and i need its V attribute Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl; dr :

```
var hasEducation = contacts.Elements("MainFoo").Elements("Foo")
 .Where(foo => foo.Elements("Bar")
                 .Any(bar => (bar.Attribute("N").Value == "Education") &&
                     (!bar.Attribute("V").Value.ToLower().Contains("some") )))
```

---

Note: I tested this with LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) use it and love it.  LinqPad is perfect for these problems.  Below is the full source for a LinqPad query to test and play yourself.

The main where is working on an element of foo.  Then it checks the elements (specifically the "Bar" elements and their attributes) for the rules you wish to apply.

The key question here is how maintainable is this type of query.  Will you be able to maintain a linq query like this?  Try working with LinqPad -- I believe it will make the modification and development of these queries easier for you (or anyone.)

---

To get a list of user ids (as John's answer) you can just add

```
.Element("User").Attribute("ID").Value;
```

to the end of the query above.

Of course that does not include John's sexy error checking.

---

```
XElement contacts = XElement.Parse (@"
<Root>
 <MainFoo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla='bla' />
        <B bla1='blablabla' />
        <C bla2='blabla' />
        <Bar N='Education' V='Some Text' />
        <Bar N='Other Node' V='Some other Text' />
        <Bar N='Yet Other Node' V='Some other other Text' />
        <Bar N='fourth Bar Node' V='Some other other otherText' />
        <User ID='1' />
     </Foo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla='bla' />
        <B bla1='blablabla' />
        <C bla2='blabla' />
        <Bar N='Education' V='Specific Text' />
        <Bar N='Other Node' V='Some other Text' />
        <Bar N='Yet Other Node' V='Some other other Text' />
        <Bar N='fourth Bar Node' V='Some other other otherText' />
        <User ID='2' />
     </Foo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla='bla' />
        <B bla1='blablabla' />
        <C bla2='blabla' /> <!--***No Bar node with N='Education' in this Foo Node, not a mistake! this might be part of the problem but this is the XML Structure and can't be changed***-->
        <Bar N='Other Node' V='Some other Text' />
        <Bar N='Yet Other Node' V='Some other other Text' />
        <Bar N='fourth Bar Node' V='Some other other otherText' />
        <User ID='3' />
     </Foo>
     <Foo>
        <A bla='bla' />
        <B bla1='blablabla' />
        <C bla2='blabla' />
        <Bar N='Education' V='Specific Text' />
        <Bar N='Other Node' V='Some other Text' />
        <Bar N='Yet Other Node' V='Some other other Text' />
        <Bar N='fourth Bar Node' V='Some other other otherText' />
        <User ID='4' />
     </Foo>
 </MainFoo>
 <OtherMainFoo></OtherMainFoo>
 <MoreMainFoo></MoreMainFoo>
</Root>");

var hasEducation = contacts.Elements("MainFoo").Elements("Foo")
      .Where(foo => foo.Elements("Bar")
               .Any(bar => (bar.Attribute("N").Value == "Education") &&
                           (!bar.Attribute("V").Value.ToLower().Contains("some") )))
      .Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep your options open, here's a solution that uses XPath instead of LINQ. This doesn't include the error checking as per John's answer, but it works all the same.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetIDs(XDocument doc, string negation)
{
    //The following xpath string will select all Foo elements that contain a Bar child
    // that has a N attribute with the value "Education" and also has a V attribute
    // that does not contain the specified string.
    string xPathString = String.Format("//Foo[(Bar/@N = 'Education') and (not(contains(Bar/@V, '{0}')))]", negation);

    return doc.Root
              .XPathSelectElements(xPathString) //Select the proper Foo elements
              .Select(a => a.Element("User").Attribute("ID").Value); //Grab the User elements under the previous Foo elements and return their ID attribute value
}
```

Comment: +1 clever solution (but search string is not case-insensitive)

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = "Some";
var query = from foo in xdoc.Descendants("Foo")
            let user = foo.Element("User")
            where user != null &&
                  foo.Elements("Bar")
                     .Any(bar => (string)bar.Attribute("N") == "Education" &&
                                 !Regex.IsMatch((string)bar.Attribute("V"), text,
                                                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            select (int)user.Attribute("ID");

// result: 2, 4
```

I used regular expression to search word in attribute of bar for two reasons - to make search case insensitive, and to take care of cases when `Bar` element does not have `V` attribute. Also you can change pattern to match word (not part of word).

---

If all `Foo` nodes have `User` element, you can remove null check for user. Also if `Bar` elements always contain `V` attribute, and you don't need case-insensitive search, then query could be simplified:

```
var query = from foo in xdoc.Descendants("Foo")                     
            where foo.Elements("Bar")
                        .Any(bar => (string)bar.Attribute("N") == "Education" &&
                                    !((string)bar.Attribute("V")).Contains(text))
            select (int)foo.Element("User").Attribute("ID");
```

Comment: Would there be any difference between using the Regex match and using `String.Equals(attribute, text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`?

Comment: @IchabodClay agree, this is also option, if there is no need to match word

Comment: Wasn't thinking straight when I made that comment. Regex is better in this situation :P

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> QueryComplexXml()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(XML);
    if (doc.Root == null)
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("No root");
    }

    var mainFoo = doc.Root.Element("MainFoo");
    if (mainFoo == null)
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("No MainFoo");
    }

    var userIDs = from foo in mainFoo.Elements("Foo")
                  where
                      foo.Elements("Bar")
                         .Any(
                             bar =>
                             bar.Attribute("N").Value == "Education" &&
                             bar.Attribute("V").Value == "Specific Text")
                  let user = foo.Element("User")
                  where user != null
                  select int.Parse(user.Attribute("ID").Value);
    return userIDs;
}
```

The code considers all of the "Foo" elements, but only those where there is a "Bar" element which has an "N" attribute of "Education" and a "V" attribute of "Specific Text" (you can put any predicate you want right there). For each of those selected elements, it pulls out the "User" elements (assuming there *is* one, and parses out and returns the "ID" attribute.

In the example XML you posted, this returns 2 and 4.

Comment: Thank you John. I did some mistake in my question, and you answer was great for the question i had, but The problem is that i need the V attribute for the Bar node in the specific Foo node for the N attribute that it's value is UserID, that is what makes it more complicated....Please look at my edit again if you don't mind...